# How to print a value to a new array if it within a bound of previous value in that array in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array:

```
StartArray=np.array([1, 2, 3, 1.4, 1.2, 0.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.9, 2.2, 3, 4 ,2.3])
```

I would like to loop through this array starting with StartArray[0] and only keep values that are within +/- .5 of the last kept value to yield:

```
EndArray=[1, 1.4, 1.2, 1.5, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3]
```

This is what I have tried so far and the results don't make sense

```
StartArray=np.array([1, 2, 3, 1.4, 1.2, 0.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.9, 2.2, 3, 4 ,2.3])
EndArray=np.empty_like(StartArray)
EndArray[0]=StartArray[0]
for i in range(len(StartArray)-1):
    if EndArray[i]+.5>StartArray[i+1]>EndArray[i]-.5:
        EndArray[i+1]=StartArray[i+1]

Out:
array([ 1.        ,  0.22559146,  0.13015365,  5.24910493,  0.63804761,
    0.6       ,  1.73143364,  1.5       ,  1.9       ,  2.2       ,
    6.82525036,  0.61641556,  6.82325036])
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble? This seems pretty straightforward to implement using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is the good structure for this job:

```
StartArray=np.array([1, 2, 3, 1.4, 1.2, 0.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.9, 2.2, 3, 4 ,2.3])
ref=StartArray[0]
End=[]
for x in StartArray:
    if abs(x- ref)<.5:
      End.append(x)
      ref=x
print(np.array(End))      

[ 1.   1.4  1.2  1.5  1.9  2.2  2.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your approach. First, you're initializing `EndArray` to be the same size as `StartArray`, but that's not what you want your desired output to be. Instead, initialize `EndArray` to be an empty list and append values as your loop through `StartArray`. Secondly, you want the output values to be within 0.5 of the last *kept* value, so you need to keep track of this.

Adapting your code:

```
StartArray=np.array([1, 2, 3, 1.4, 1.2, 0.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.9, 2.2, 3, 4 ,2.3])
EndArray=[]

last_kept = StartArray[0]
EndArray.append(last_kept)
for i in range(len(StartArray)-1):
    if np.abs(StartArray[i+1] - last_kept) < 0.5:
        last_kept = StartArray[i+1]
        EndArray.append(last_kept)

# convert back to numpy array
EndArray = np.array(EndArray)
```